# Any way to extract a live wallpaper from a theme on the theme store?

Tags: root-access, themes, live-wallpaper

I would like to extract/save/download a live wallpaper from a theme which I downloaded. Is there anyway to do this without rooting my phone?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to extract the APK file and check out what assets and resources you find inside. Just unzip the APK file.

Comment: @Robert is this approach still possible, considering that LiveWallpaper also uses `Service` component and some code to work?

Comment: @AndrewT. Of course a live wall paper is not a video nor animated gif, it is an app that generates animation by code so you can not make it run outside of the app itself. But depending on the live background parts of the background may be contained within the app in form of images.